# Doctrine - subquery in from

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a query in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, t.name AS name
    FROM tag t
    INNER JOIN video_has_tag v USING (idTag)
    GROUP BY v.idTag
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 10
) as tags ORDER BY name
```

and I want to write this in doctrine. How I can do that? I wrote:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('COUNT(t.idtag) as count, t.name')
        ->from('Tag t')
        ->innerJoin('t.VideoHasTag v')
        ->groupBy('v.idTag')
        ->orderBy('count DESC, t.name')
        ->limit(30)
        ->execute();
```

But I can't put it in "from" to sort by name.

Comment: What do you mean by: 'put it in "from" to sort by name'?

Comment: does doctrine support subquery?  maybe put the whole query in from(...)

Comment: @Chris Williams: look at mysql query :)
@Yada: When I put whole query in from() Doctrine say me that "(SELECT" table doesn't exist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a answer:

```
$q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
$q->addComponent('t', 'Tag')
    ->select('{t.name}, {t.count}')
    ->from('(SELECT COUNT(*) as count, t.name,t.idtag
        FROM Tag t
            INNER JOIN Video_Has_Tag v USING(idTag)
        GROUP BY v.idTag
        ORDER BY count DESC
        LIMIT 50) t')
    ->orderBy('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

I use **Doctrine 1.2** and **Symfony 1.4** and `Doctrine_RawSql` works with subqueries. You can then `addComponent` for models.

Something **worth** mentioning is that you can't directly use **`Doctrine_Query` objects** as subqueries **BUT** you can easily get the SQL form via **`getSqlQuery()`** method or even **`getSqlQueryPart`** and use the result for the subquery.

**`getSqlQueryPart`** is useful in rebuilding only certain parts of a query.

Comment: There are no such thing as Doctrine_RawSql()

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine cannot do a subquery in the FROM clause (nor can it JOIN to a subquery). Your current Doctrine query is going to sort by count and then by name. Is that not what you are wanting?

Comment: Now it's sort by count and when is the same value it's sort by name. I want to get standart tag cloud: 10 tags with greatest count sorted by name

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine will let you put a subquery in the FROM clause.  However, it only can take DQL text statements in the subquery, you can't actually use another query object.  If you rewrite your DQL subquery in textual form, you should be able to use it.

See [this page of the documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:subqueries) for an example.  The example puts the DQL subquery in the WHERE clause, but it mentions that you can use subqueries in the FROM clause.

Comment: I wrote:
        $tags = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('(SELECT COUNT(*) as count, t.name FROM Tag t INNER JOIN t.VideoHasTag v GROUP BY v.idTag ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 30) as tags')
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->execute();
and I get "Couldn't find class (SELECT "

Comment: Doctrine does *NOT* support sub-queries in the FROM clause, despite what the docs say:  http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/7572bf091e822b1f/d72952f5aa1378ee